# AngularJS: Multiple file selection not working in apk build

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ng-file-upload

I'm using `ng-file-upload` in my hybrid app for uploading multiples files in same request. It is working perfectly fine in testing environment. But When i build apk it don't let user to select multiple files at a same time. This is the [plunker i'm following](http://jsfiddle.net/danialfarid/huhjo9jm/5/) And my uploading file code is:

```
<a href="#" class="pull-right" style="color:white;" 
ngf-max-files="10" ngf-pattern="'image/*,.jpg,.JPG,.PNG,.png,.gif,.GIF'" ngf-accept="image/*"
multiple ng-model="file"
ngf-select="uploadFiles($files, $invalidFiles)" ngf-multiple="true"
ngf-max-height="6000" ngf-max-size="100MB" >
<span class="TextSha">Next </span><span class="fa fa-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
</a>
```

I have tried `multiple` and also set `ngf-multiple="true"` but still not let user to select multiple files at a same time. I'm using angularJS v1.2. I have tried this apk build on latest devices too but still they are only able to select single file at a time.

Comment: How did you resolve this issue?

Comment: added dependencies

Comment: What dependencies. Can you give a little working snippet?

Comment: `<plugin name="cordova-plugin-file" />`
`<plugin name="cordova-plugin-file-transfer" />`

Comment: `<plugin name="cordova-plugin-image-picker" spec="^1.1.3" />`